# Documentation for Instagram API for link, data, url etc.

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, instagram

I have some js which is retrieving instagram data via the API for me. I am using this function which works fine:

```
$(".instagram-wrapper").append("<a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link +"'><img src='" + data.data[i].images.thumbnail.url +"' /></a>");
```

But I had to use trial and error for the link parameter, as the code I was using referred to was written like this:

```
<img src='" + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url +"'></img>
```

But I cannot find documentation for the images.low_resolution etc. Does anyone know where this might be it doesn't appear to be under the instagram developers site.

TIA
Luke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/

is it not there under the `GET /images/{media-id}` call within the images object? I see a `images.low_resolution` key there.

Comment: Cool thank you! I wish it was documented as well (i.e not just written out as JSON).

Comment: JSON is kinda self documenting though no?

Comment: @ncremins I just now stumbled on this question in my search for a full Instagram API reference. The endpoint overviews in the developer pages contain example JSON responses but they aren't complete. At the time of writing there is still no way to know which objects and properties a response might contain except by piecing together all of the examples yourself.